# dyld: Symbol not found: _os_release

Tags: xcode, macos, lua

I rarely build anything from source, so I really have no idea what's going on here, but have done good few hours of googling and still can't solve it...

I have installed xcode from app store, downloaded newest lua and here is what happens:

```
cd lua-5.3.0

make macosx

dyld: Symbol not found: _os_release
Referenced from:  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
Expected in: /usr/local/terrame/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
make: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to     the Xcode folder is set correctly!
make: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch
```

I then run

```
xcode-select -r
```

and still get

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _os_release
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
 Expected in: /usr/local/terrame/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
```

If I then once again try

```
make macosx
```

the first error comes back at me:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _os_release
Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
Expected in: /usr/local/terrame/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
make: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
make: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch
```

I have tried installing an extension to Lua before, called terrame (terrame.org) so that's what the folder path refers to...

EDIT (answering comments)

```
which make
/usr/bin/make
```

Comment: Are you running `/usr/bin/make` ? What does `which make` print?

Comment: It looks so (see EDIT to the question)